# How can I create a safe counter in MySQL (I'm looking for a general solution)?

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency

How can I prevent an update that is based on data that has been changed after it was read. In the counter case, how can I prevent setting a counter to be 0+1 when someone already did that after I read the 0.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, you'd want to do `UPDATE table SET counter=counter+1`.

In a more general context where this sort of simple integer math isn't suitable, you'll want to look into the concept of [transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).